# Printf 4 items per line

Tags: c, loops

I have some values, and I want to print them in groups of 4 items per  line!

```
for (i=0;<i<18;i++)
    number[i]=(2*i)+5;
for (i=0;i<18;i++)
    printf ("[%d]", number[i]; /* Gives me the full numbers consecutively */
```

Should I use a counter to start counting the elements? And when the counter becomes 3 to change line, or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: `{ printf ("[%d]", number[i]); if(i && i % 3 == 0) puts(""); }` as body of for-loop

Comment: @BLUEPIXY-- "`if(i && i % 3 == 0) ...`": this will print a line of 4 items, and then 3 items in each following line.

Comment: Note that the question title originally specified 3 items per line, but the body emphasized 4 items per line.  The confusion over 3 vs 4 per line can legitimately stem from that.  If there are N items per line, you print a newline after a counter reaches N-1; I think the remaining 3 in the question is an example of 'N-1'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int print_number_by_group(int *number, size_t size, size_t group) {
  if (number == NULL || group == 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (size == 1) {
    printf("[%d]\n", number[0]);
  }
  else if (size != 0) {
    printf("[%d]", number[0]);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i++) {
      if (i % group == 0)
        printf("\n");
      printf("[%d]", number[i]);
    }
    if (size % group != 0) {
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  int number[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17};

  print_number_by_group(number, sizeof number / sizeof *number, 4);
}
```

---

Don't try this at home, it was just for fun:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int print_number_by_group(FILE *stream, int *number, size_t size,
                                 size_t group) {
  if (number == NULL || group == 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  size_t i = 0;
  size_t j = 1;
loop : {
  int num = number[i];
  if (j == group) {
    if (fprintf(stream, "[%d]\n", num) < 0) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (++i >= size) {
      return 0;
    }
    j = 1;
  } else {
    if (++i >= size) {
      if (fprintf(stream, "[%d]\n", num) < 0) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    } else {
      if (fprintf(stream, "[%d]", num) < 0) {
        return 1;
      }
    }
    j++;
  }
}
  goto loop;
}

int main(void) {
  int number[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17};

  print_number_by_group(stdout, number, sizeof number / sizeof *number, 3);
}
```

Comment: What if you changed your mind and wanted 6 per line? Or 10 per line? Or some arbitrary run-time value per-line? Hard coding four at a time like this limits flexibility.

Comment: @e0k then better do it with loop... and the optimizer probably will take the loop away.

Comment: @Nick Let the optimizer unroll loops or whatever it wants, but it's not going to change the format string.

Comment: @e0k compiller knows the format string. printf("%s\n", x) is often reduced to puts()

Answer (score 0):

This isn't rocket science, but can be done in a single loop with a few lines of code.

```
for(size_t i=0; i<18; i++)
{
  printf("[%3.d]", number[i]);
  if(i%4 == 4-1)
  {
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: The last line isn't terminated by a newline if the length of the data isn't a multiple of the group size (4 in this case). One way to fix that is to declare the loop control variable `i` outside the loop and then add 'if (i % 4 != 0) putchar('\n');` after the loop.